# Powerapps : how to use submit button to store values of form controls into excel online

Tags: excel, submit, office365, powerapps

I am building a powerapps where I need to submit the form controls like radio, dropdown selected,textinput values into excel online . Also in excel I need to predefine the header column names like Product name, Product Value , Product weight , Product manufactured date in excel so that when I submit the form in powerapp, it will get stored into excel online under these column headers.
Please tell me how to do so as I am very much new to powerapps .

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Have you searched for existing discussions?  Help is available if you have a specific problem.  Start here for information:  https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-patch/

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have the table format(i.e., Having all the column names) in excel ready, Place it in OneDrive or Create a SharePoint list.

Open PowerApps then select Onedrive as your source(if the data is in OneDrive), PowerApps will create an App by default. That will do most of your job, if not, you can edit the App with some Excel like function.

Play with it, you will understand it.